# How to store output for every xargs instance separately

Tags: linux, bash

`cat domains.txt | xargs -P10 -I % ffuf -u %/FUZZ -w wordlist.txt -o output.json`

Ffuf is used for directory and file bruteforcing while domains.txt contains valid HTTP and HTTPS URLs like http://example.com, http://example2.com. I used xargs to speed up the process by running 10 parallel instances. But the problem here is I am unable to store output for each instance separately and output.json is getting override by every running instance. Is there anything we can do to make `output.json` unique for every instance so that all data gets saved separately. I tried `ffuf/$(date '+%s').json` instead but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 4):

Sure. Just name your output file using the domain. E.g.:

```
xargs -P10 -I % ffuf -u %/FUZZ -w wordlist.txt -o output-%.json < domains.txt
```

(I dropped `cat` because it was unnecessary.)

---

I missed the fact that your `domains.txt` file is actually a list of URLs rather than a list of domain names. I think the easiest fix is just to simplify `domains.txt` to be just domain names, but you could also try something like:

```
xargs -P10 -I % sh -c 'domain="%"; ffuf -u %/FUZZ -w wordlist.txt -o output-${domain##*/}.json' < domains.txt
```

Comment: but `http:///example.com` is not a valid file name. i wanted to use $(echo % | awk -F/ '{print $3}').json but it doesnt work. Can we get around that?

Comment: This works fine. Great. But if I have like `http://example.com`, `https://example.com`. The files will override again. So we need to separate http with https. What do you say?

Comment: It seems like the easiest thing to do would be replace your command with a small shell script that takes the % as it's only argument, parses what you want for file name (Maybe just replace the // with a : using sed) then run your command.

Comment: `xargs -P5 -I {} sh -c 'domain="{}"; ffuf -u {}/FUZZ -w wordlist.txt-o ${domain##*/}-${domain%%:*}.json' < domains.txt`
This worked fine. Took me a lot of time to come up with this. Have to RTFM about pattern matching in parameter substitution. But the solution is here. Thank you all for you help.

Answer (score -1):

```
cat domains.txt | xargs -P10 -I % sh -c "ping % > output.json.%"
```

Like this and your "%" can be part of the file name. (I changed your command to ping for my testing)

So maybe something more like this:

```
cat domains.txt | xargs -P10 -I % sh -c "ffuf -u %/FUZZ -w wordlist.txt -o output.json.%
```

"

I would replace your ffuf command with the following script, and call this from the xargs command. It just strips out the invalid file name characters and replaces them with a dot then runs the command:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

URL=$1
FILE="`echo $URL |  sed 's/:\/\//\./g'`"
ffuf -u ${URL}/FUZZ -w wordlist.txt -o output-${FILE}.json
```

Comment: domains.txt contains `http://example.com` and `https://example.com` so while writing the file it will fail. instead ping try with curl